# PHP impossible to unzipped file

Tags: php

I wouldlike to unzip file in my upload directory but I don't understand why it doesn't work. (PHP version 7.2.14)

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$path = 'uploads/';

 if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        echo 'file uploaded  ';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path.$fileName);

        if ($fileType='application/x-zip-compressed')
          $zip = new ZipArchive;
          if ($zip->open($fileName) === TRUE) {
              $zip->extractTo($path);
              $zip->close();
              echo 'ok';
        } else {
            echo 'failed';
        }   
    }
?>
```

I tried to logged $zip but apparently my zip doesn't want to open because I have directly `'failed'` (`'echo failed'`)

Comment: Try like this `$zip->open($path.$fileName)`

Comment: oh lol ! my bad thank you ! it works !!